# How to undo selection in Atom without using mouse or arrow keys

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, selection, atom-editor

If I select something using any of the various methods Atom (and other packages provide) and want to leave the cursor where it's at, but undo the selection itself, is there a way to do that with a keyboard shortcut?

I tried Esc, but to no avail. I can easily use the arrow keys, or click with the mouse, but I'd rather hit a shortcut without having to move my hands off home row. Lazy me. :)

Comment: Per the close question dialog: "Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming." Since Atom falls under this, and since there are plenty of how-do-I-do-this-in-Atom questions on SO - including quite a few regarding selection - I'd ask you to consider not closing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want that home row, no mouse efficiency, consider installing Vim-Mode-Plus on atom.  I'm using it, and when I press escape, it removes the highlighting.

Comment: ooh - great.  I will give it a shot :)